# Toggle DIV visibility in gridview eventhandler in code behind not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, lifecycle

I have the following gridview and "loadingbar" div:

```
<asp:GridView ID="importLogGV" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataKeyNames="id" 
    OnRowDeleting="DeleteStuff" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="searchListGridView">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id">
    [...]
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="120">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel" CommandName="Delete" Text='Delete' runat="server" 
         OnClientClick="return confirm('Really delete?');" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<div id="deleting" style="text-align: center" Visible="False" runat="server" 
 ClientIDMode="Static">Delete in progress...<br />
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/ajax-loadingbar.gif"/>
</div>
```

While the eventhandler "DeleteStuff" runs (it does lots of database things than can take up to 10 seconds) in code behind I need to show the "deleting" div, and when the eventhandler finishes it need to hide the div again.

Here's my eventhandler for the delete in codebehind:

```
protected void DeleteStuff(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    deleting.Visible = true;

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    deleting.Visible = false;
}
```

I've tried using style:display instead of the visible attribute, I've tried using a asp:panel instead of a div, but whatever I do, the eventhandler runs but the div is never shown while it runs.

I thought of showing the div with javascript when the user clicks the delete button, but how would I be able to hide it again then after the DeleteStuff process finishes?

Comment: Whenever you click the button to delete, a submit request is sent to the server and your page starts to refresh. The page will be re-rendered _after_ the method on the server finishes execution. So whatever you do inside your method, the last effect will retain. If you want to show _busy_ text on the browser, ajax is the way; you will have to use update panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you click the button to delete, a submit request is sent to the server and your page starts to refresh. The page will be re-rendered after the method on the server finishes execution. So whatever you do inside your method, the last effect will retain. If you want to show busy text on the browser, ajax is the way; you will have to use update panels. Try this:

**The javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDeleteConfirm()
    {
        var isSure = confirm('Really delete?');
        if(isSure)
        {
            document.getElementById("deleting").style['display'] = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

**aspx markup:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="importLogGV" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        DataKeyNames="id" 
        OnRowDeleting="DeleteStuff" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="searchListGridView">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id">
        [...]
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="120">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel" CommandName="Delete" Text='Delete' runat="server" 
             OnClientClick="return showDeleteConfirm();" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <div id="deleting" style="text-align: center" style="display:none" runat="server" 
     ClientIDMode="Static">Delete in progress...<br />
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/ajax-loadingbar.gif"/>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void DeleteStuff(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    //... Real task here
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    deleteing.Style['display'] = 'none';
}
```

By the way, you need to add a `ScriptManager` on the page.

Comment: Thank you, this works great! It also cleared up why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
protected void DeleteStuff(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckAccess())
    {
        deleting.Visible = true;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);   
        deleting.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => DeleteStuff(sender, e)));
    }
}
```

Btw, you should probably use a Timer instead of Thread.Sleep(5000).

Comment: Thread.Sleep is just a shortcut for all the database stuff that happens in the eventhandler :)